# D7000 and Lightroom "Direct acquisition" how to store also on SD

Tags: lightroom, nikon-d7000

I've tried to use "direct acquisition" function in Lightroom with my Nikon D7000. It works like a sharm but I notice that pictures goes directly on my PC without being saved on SD. Is there an option to force a copy also in the memory card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After deep searching I found that the right function name is "Tethered Capture" and that there is a Nikon limitation acquiring images in tethered mode. It seems there is no way to save images both on SD and PC while Canon can do it.